# Spam becoming frequent?

Tags: discussion

Today, seeing AskUbuntu, it seems that spam is getting frequent, 30 minutes a spam thread is being posted. The most recent one was about "making people to look younger". The first one i saw today was about a game..

Comment: Oh, we've had times when the spam has been in much larger quantities and much more frequent than anything you've seen today.

Comment: In a weird way, it's fun to shoot at. Keeps you young  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spam comes randomly. Sometimes nothing for a week, sometimes dozens within a single hour.

Maybe somebody who really tries to get some people click their links thinks that their chances are higher if they send a wave of spam posts, maybe it's just coincidence.

As long as it gets back to a lower rate after an hour or a day again, there's nothing to worry. We've handled all spam waves successfully in the past and will continue to do that in the future!

Comment: The spammers just don't get it that this community is too powerful for them!  **;-)**